# Google Dashboard with spreadsheet in HTML

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I'm working on a new project that just fell into my lap that is a bit out of my scope. I've been looking into how to create a google chart and how to feed it data from a google spreadsheet without luck so far.

I've been looking [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls) for information but it's I'm just not able to make the connection between manipulating the data when included in the file vs querying out to a google spreadsheet to grab data.

I've been looking at the code below trying to figure out what would need to be replaced and tweaked to make it reach out to a google spreadsheet but I've been unable to get anything I try working and there isn't much in the way of youtube guides for something as specific as this.

`

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the controls package.
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['controls']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates a dashboard, a range slider and a pie chart,
      // passes in the data and draws it.
      function drawDashboard() {

        // Create our data table.
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Name', 'Donuts eaten'],
          ['Michael' , 5],
          ['Elisa', 7],
          ['Robert', 3],
          ['John', 2],
          ['Jessica', 6],
          ['Aaron', 1],
          ['Margareth', 8]
        ]);

        // Create a dashboard.
        var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
            document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

        // Create a range slider, passing some options
        var donutRangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
          'controlType': 'NumberRangeFilter',
          'containerId': 'filter_div',
          'options': {
            'filterColumnLabel': 'Donuts eaten'
          }
        });

        // Create a pie chart, passing some options
        var pieChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          'chartType': 'PieChart',
          'containerId': 'chart_div',
          'options': {
            'width': 300,
            'height': 300,
            'pieSliceText': 'value',
            'legend': 'right'
          }
        });

        // Establish dependencies, declaring that 'filter' drives 'pieChart',
        // so that the pie chart will only display entries that are let through
        // given the chosen slider range.
        dashboard.bind(donutRangeSlider, pieChart);

        // Draw the dashboard.
        dashboard.draw(data);
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the dashboard-->
    <div id="dashboard_div">
      <!--Divs that will hold each control and chart-->
      <div id="filter_div"></div>
      <div id="chart_div"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

`

Comment: the literal fed into the data variable can be replaced by a call to a ranges [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())

Answer (score 0):

You can start by reading [*Creating a Chart from a Separate Spreadsheet*](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets#creating-a-chart-from-a-separate-spreadsheet).

> Typically, people create Google Charts by populating a data table and drawing the chart using that data. If you want to retrieve the data from a Google Spreadsheet instead, you'll query the spreadsheet to retrieve the data to be charted:

```
function drawChart() {
var query = new google.visualization.Query(URL);
query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
var data = response.getDataTable();
var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('columnchart'));
chart.draw(data, null);
}
```

---

> ## [Query Source Ranges](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets#query-source-ranges)
>
> The query source URL specifies what part of a spreadsheet to use in the query: a specific cell, range of cells, rows, or columns, or a whole spreadsheet. Specify the range using the "range=" syntax, for example:
>
> `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XWJLkAwch5GXAt_7zOFDcg8Wm8Xv29_8PWuuW15qmAE/gviz/tq?range=A1:C4`
>
> Here are a few examples that demonstrate the syntax:
>
> - **A1:B10** - A range from cell A1 through B10
> - **5:7** - Rows 5-7
> - **D:F** - Columns D-F